# Accessing my paypal transaction list from the paypal Rest API

Tags: rest, paypal

I am trying to access my transaction list from the paypal Rest API. I
want to see all the payments I sent and received for, say, the last 3
weeks.

I *think* this can be done by paypal REST api ("paypal-sdk-rest" gem
in ruby). However, I cannot find the exact command. I checked the
Paypal Rest API reference (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) ,
and there is a "search for transactions", but that seems to be under
the heading for "Billing Agreements". There is also a "search for
invoices" under invoicing heading. But these aren't invoiced items. I
just want the transaction list.

Am I using the right sdk? Is there another REST api that does this?
what, specifically, is the command?

Answer (score 0):

The official REST API SDK for Ruby is located at : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

It comes packaged with [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/tree/master/samples), that could help you get started really fast. You could follow the instructions on how to run samples, or install sdk.

Here is the sample for getting all paypal transactions in Payments API: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/all.rb

```
# #GetPaymentList Sample
# This sample code demonstrate how you can
# retrieve a list of all Payment resources
# you've created using the Payments API.
# Note various query parameters that you can
# use to filter, and paginate through the
# payments list.
# API used: GET /v1/payments/payments
require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
include PayPal::SDK::REST
include PayPal::SDK::Core::Logging

# ###Retrieve
# Retrieve the PaymentHistory  by calling the
# `all` method
# on the Payment class
# Refer the API documentation
# for valid values for keys
# Supported paramters are :count, :next_id
@payment_history = Payment.all( :count => 5 )

# List Payments
logger.info "List Payment:"
@payment_history.payments.each do |payment|
  logger.info "  -> Payment[#{payment.id}]"
end
```

Comment: This doesn't pull up any of my transaction history: <PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::PaymentHistory:0x00000002325058 @error=nil, @count=0>  
  
I know that the api works because I can pull up an arbitrary transaction_id via the "Capture" class. This pulls up info, for instance: Capture.find("6H858595U07730403")